Send network packets from a kernel driver
I've been learning about Windows related stuff lately, I started by writing something very simple. But I can't figure out how to use WFP or NDIS. I want to send a TCP Packet to 192.168.1.105:32500. Anyone knows how to do this? (I'm writing the kdriver in C)
I looked at some WFP Templates, I still don't understand it

If all you want to do is send/recv data then Winsock Kernel is the most appropriate API to use.

Hey luke, thanks I checked that out and I couldn't really find any proper documentation about it, what I mean is that I'm not sure how to use it.

That link provides extensive documentation. There is also a sample project at https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/network/wsk/echosrv

unfortunately that code didn't work. I tried making my own I failed miserably.
